# Removing module also attempts to remove PackageManagement

Tags: powershell

When removing a custom-built module for the first time in a PowerShell session using Remove-Module, the module PackageManagement is attempted to be removed as well. I do not understand where this behavior comes from.

I've been building up a PowerShell module for interactions with an internal API.

The module's layout is very similar to the PoshDog project: https://github.com/simnyc/poshdog/tree/master/PoshDog

A skeleton project that exhibits the same problem is located here: https://github.com/Christophoclese/powershell-module-template

```
PS C:\Users\cbarton\Desktop\GitHub\ModuleTemplate> .\Test-Module.ps1
WARNING: Did not find an installed version of ModuleTemplate-test. Are you testing with Test-Module.ps1?

Module ModuleTemplate-test (0.0.8) loaded.
Please contact someauthor@somedomain.com with questions.

PS C:\Users\cbarton\Desktop\GitHub\ModuleTemplate> remove-module ModuleTemplate-test -Verbose
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove-Module" on target "Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement (Path: 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.3.1\fullclr\Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.dll')".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove-Module" on target "Microsoft.PackageManagement (Path: 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.3.1\fullclr\Microsoft.PackageManagement.dll')".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove-Module" on target "PackageManagement (Path: 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.3.1\PackageManagement.psm1')".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove-Module" on target "ModuleTemplate-test (Path:
'C:\Users\cbarton\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ModuleTemplate-test\ModuleTemplate-test.psm1')".
remove-module : Unable to remove the module 'PackageManagement' because it is required by 'PowerShellGet'. Add the
Force parameter to your command to remove the module.
At line:1 char:1
+ remove-module ModuleTemplate-test -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PackageManagement:PSModuleInfo) [Remove-Module], InvalidOperationExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleIsRequired,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveModuleCommand
```

The module is actually removed from the current session despite the error that is presented.

I would expect that no errors are presented and removing my module does not cause PowerShell to attempt to unload PackageManagement.

How can I dive deeper into why PowerShell is taking this action on my behalf?

Comment: This could be a bug. If you can reproduce it in [PowerShell 6 Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), then you can [report it using their bug tracker](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues). They've been responsive and helpful regarding all of my bug reports. Although, you'll probably need to include code from the module, how you load it, and reproduce the problem with the least code possible (such as an empty or small module file). Minimizing the code for the bug report may allow you to solve the problem yourself or to determine the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: I've added an example that's been tested against PowerShell 5.1.16299.1146. I'll see about trying to run the code on PowerShell 6 Core.